# PDO getting values

Tags: php, pdo

I made a blog. Everything is working correctly except for one thing; being able to compare my `id` in order to open the appropriate article.

I'm using `FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'm checking `$_GET` for an `id`:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] == $blogid['id'])) { **PROBLEM IS WITH $blogid
$row = $sth->fetch()
//... Code to display html and db values
```

If true, it shows the entire blog post. Else it displays all the blog intros:

```
<?php } else { ?>
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()) {  ?>
//... Code to display html and db values
```

How can I access the `id` in my `if` statement? If I do something like:

```
$blogid = $sth->fetch()
```

it screws up `$row = $sth->fetch()` by reordering the posts

EDIT Query added:

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT id, title, slug, body, image, author, date, category from blog ORDER BY date DESC');
```

Comment: Please show us your query. Instead of checking if the blog ID is the same as the one from `$_GET`, you should be passing a condition to the query with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @JamWaffles - Query added above. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using PDO and MySQL slightly wrong here. Instead of getting all the blog posts and checking to see whether the one you've got has the correct ID, you should only get *one* blog post (row) from the DB using a `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
SELECT id, title, ... FROM blog 
WHERE id=[ID from $_GET] 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

PDO handles this for you fantastically well by allowing you to use placeholders:

```
SELECT id, title, ... FROM blog 
WHERE id=:theBlogID 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Here, I've used the placeholder `:theBlogID` which will be replaced by the `$_GET` parameter .

Using PDO, your final code needs to prepare the query, bind a parameter to it, execute it and then get the result (checking if there actually is a result using `PDO::rowCount()`) something like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, title, ... FROM blog 
                      WHERE id=:theBlogID 
                      ORDER BY date DESC');

$sth->bindParam(':theBlogID', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);    // Bind the ID from $_GET to the placeholder

$result = $sth->execute();    // Execute (run) the query

if($result->rowCount()) {    // Have we found any blog posts with the ID specified?
    $data = $result->fetchAll();

    foreach($data as $post) {
        // Print out your blog post
    }
}
```

It's not clear how much of the above you currently have as you only give one or two line snippets here and there, but this should give a good outline of what you need to do.

Comment: so, I'm a little confused. If I understand this right, your code will check if the `id` is set, if so it will run a `foreach` loop. Is that correct? The `foreach` will then return all rows matching the `id`. From there I should be able to access everything by using `echo $row['date']` correct?

Comment: if the `if` statement return `false` would I add an `else` statement and run the code I have above to display everything?

Comment: Correctomundo. If you want to add a "No posts!" message then yes, you just need to add an `else` to the end of the existing `if()`.

Comment: That's where I'm still a bit confused. How does this display the page with the intro. I'm trying to achieve what SO does. There is a snippet(slug) on the main page. Then clicking on it takes you to the full post(body).

Comment: To get a list of slugs, simply remove the `WHERE` clause so it fetches all the results, as well as `$sth->bindParam()` because it's not needed, display the list of slugs and link to each post with an ID in `$_GET` to a page that _does_ use a placeholder and ID. The code above is to get one blog post, so I suppose a `foreach()` isn't really necessary.

Comment: We're sooo close but still sooo far :) It's tough to describe what I'm doing, but I think your answer will help me. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Not a problem. If you really get stuck, edit your post with some code snippets and I'll update my answer.